# Axios & Typescript: Return array object with only the props specified

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, next.js

I'm trying to build an API that fetches the ERC20 tokens in my balance. For this, I'm using nextjs & axios with TypeScript.

The issue I have is that the response outputed by my endpoint returns way too much data, rather than the only 3 props defined in my `Token` type. Here is how it goes:

**util/api.ts**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import console from 'console';


type Token = {
  contractAddress: string;
  tokenName: string;
  tokenSymbol: string;
};

async function getTokens(walletAddress: string) {
  const params = {
    action: 'tokentx',
    address: walletAddress,
    offset: 5,
    startblock: 0,
    endblock: 999999999,
    sort: 'asc',
    apikey: 'XXXXX'
  }

  try {
    const response = await axios.request<Token[]>({
      url: 'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account',
      params: params
    }).then((response) => {
      return response.data
    });

    return response
  } catch (error) {
    if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
      console.log('error message: ', error.message);
      return error.message;
    } else {
      console.log('unexpected error: ', error);
      return 'An unexpected error occurred';
    }
  }
}

export async function getWalletBalance(walletAddress: string) {
  let tokens = await getTokens(walletAddress)
  return tokens
}
```

**pages/api/balances/[network]/[wallet.ts]**

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import NextCors from "nextjs-cors";
import { getWalletBalance } from "../../../../util/api";

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  await NextCors(req, res, {
    methods: ["GET"],
    origin: "*",
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  });

  const { wallet } = req.query as { wallet: string };

  try {
    const balance = await getWalletBalance(wallet);
    res.json({ balance });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: (e as Error).message });
  }
};
```

How can I make it so that getTokens() only returns an array of Token with only the `contractAddress`, `tokenName`, `tokenSymbol` props, in order for the endpoint to output only the JSON I need?

Comment: Did the answer help or do you need anything else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to reduce the data returned from the `api.etherscan.io`
in your own proxy api you'd need to filter out only the props you need. you can achieve it like so:

```
.then((response) => {
      return response.data.map(x=>({
         contractAddress:x.contractAddress
         tokenName:x.tokenName
         tokenSymbol:x.tokenSymbol
    });
  })
```

I don't know much about the 3rd party endpoint but I assuming its a REST endpoint so you couldn't take advantage of Graphql's ability to reduce overfetching by specifying the properties of the type you're interested in.

Comment: Indeed, that's seems to be the proper way to do this. Thanks!